# Sort string list with dates in C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting, date

I have a `List<string>` with dates.
My list is:

```
{"01/01/2013","10/01/2013","20/01/2013"}
```

I want to sort the list to look like this:

```
{"20/01/2013","10/01/2013","01/01/2013"}
```

How can I make this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

With linq:

```
var list = new List<string> {"01/01/2013", "10/01/2013", "20/01/2013"};
var orderedList = list.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

**UPDATE (according questions in comments):**

You can treat invalid dates like this (invalid date is there treated as `default(DateTime)`):

```
var list = new List<string> { "01/01/2013", "10/01/2013", "N/A" , "20/01/2013"  };
var orderedList2 = list.OrderByDescending(x =>
            {
                DateTime dt;
                DateTime.TryParse(x, out dt);
                return dt;
            });
```

Or if you want to have invalid datetime as first item in the list:

```
var orderedList3 = list.OrderByDescending(x =>
            {
                DateTime dt;
                if (!DateTime.TryParse(x, out dt)) return DateTime.MaxValue;
                return dt;
            });
```

You can also filter the invalid dates out:

```
var filteredList = list.Where(x =>
            {
                DateTime dt;
                return DateTime.TryParse(x, out dt);
            }).Select(DateTime.Parse).OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

Or even better:

```
var filteredList = list.Select(x =>
        {
            DateTime dt;
            return new {valid = DateTime.TryParse(x, out dt), date = dt};
        }).Where(x => x.valid).Select(x => x.date).OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

Comment: How about if there is an invalid datetime string? Is there any way to alter that invalid datetime with a specific string?

Comment: What if there are strings as well? Like missing? how do you sort

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use string representations of data - we're all living in object-oriented world :)

Best way would be to convert these strings into actual DateTime objects and sort them in reverse order via linq:

```
var dates = Array.ConvertAll(dateStrings, x => DateTime.Parse(x));
return dates.OrderByDesc(x => x);
```

Another way would be to implement custom sorting function, see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx). Then you'd just use it in a sort function:

```
DateAsStringComparer myComparer = new DateAsStringComparer();
dateStrings.Sort(myComparer);
```

Comment: +1 because you didn't bother with the string comparison like I did :)

Comment: actually, you don't need the lambda, you can do it like this -Array.ConvertAll(dateStrings,DateTime.Parse)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
List<string> s = new List<string>() { "01/01/2013", "10/01/2013", "20/01/2013" };
var d = s.OrderByDescending(i => DateTime.ParseExact(i, "dd/MM/yyyy", null));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use `List<string>` instead of `List<DateTime>`?

```
List<DateTime> dates = ...

dates.OrderByDescending(c => c).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm sure he had his reasons. I need it as well, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are the UK/AUS format (Day/Month/Year), you can sort them using `OrderByDescending`:

```
List<string> dates = new List<string>() { "01/01/2013", "10/01/2013", "20/10/2013" };

foreach (var date in dates.OrderByDescending(x => x))
    Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Personally I would convert them to `DateTime` objects first..

Answer (score 0):

To convert DateTime string of custom format to `string` of unified format, you can adopt following simple and `safe` snippet.

```cs
    string formatStr = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
    string result = Convert.ToDateTime(inputStr).ToString(formatStr);
```

Inside the code, `formatStr` can be any possible forms the `DateTime` class can accept, you can set it as the format you need, here you can just use `dd/MM/yyyy` which is matched with your target format string such as "20/01/2013".

So for your case, the code can be simple as below:

```cs
    List<string> list = new List<string> { "01/01/2013", "10/01/2013", "20/01/2013" };
    var listAfterSorting = list.OrderByDescending(t => 
        Convert.ToDateTime(t).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
            .ToList());
```

While in some cases, using `ParseExact` to parse a data time string, it will throws error/exception `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`, in that case if you turn to use `TryParseExact`, the result is probably `default(DateTime)`= `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` because of parsing failed. Therefore, I do not recommend `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact`.