# how to sort date in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I have many date in one variable like:

```
var date = hfAllDates.Value.Split('#');
```

there are four date(01/01/2016,22/01/2016,18/01/2016,05/01/2016) in date variable .

how to sort date.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the `hfAllDates` exactly? You are not sorting anything, you are splitting something but that's not clear as well.

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: is the type of date `string[]`? Then you may need to convert each element to `DateTime` first. Then you can sort it easily.

Comment: This isn't quite a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667754/sort-string-list-with-dates-in-c-sharp), since that one deals with lists rather than arrays. However, considering how easy it is to convert an array to a list, the answer on that question still applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add namespace `using System.Linq;`

and use LINQ Query

in ascending order

```
  var orderedDateList = date.OrderBy(x => DateTime.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

in Descending oreder

```
var orderedDateList = date.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert `date` from `string[]` to `List<DateTime>` first:

```
List<DateTime> dtList = date.Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Then you can easily sort it:

```
dtList.Sort();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq's `OrderBy`:

`var sortedDates = date.OrderBy(x => DateTime.Parse(x));`

or

`var sortedDates = date.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x));`

if you are needed to sort dates descending

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *Linq*:

```
var date = hfAllDates.Value.Split('#')
  .Select(line => DateTime.Parse(x))
  .OrderBy(x => x)
  .ToList();
```